# Show/hide number of rows based on "n"

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to show/hide a number of rows based on "n".

The rows I'm trying to show or hide span from rows 21 to 70. My input cell for "n" is B14.

Say if B14 is 2 then I only want rows 21 and 22 to be visible (23 to 70 hidden). If B14 is 48 then rows 21 to 68 visible and so forth.

Can someone help me with the macro required to achieve this?

Comment: `Range("A21").Resize(Range("B14").Value).EntireRow.Hidden = True`

Comment: 70 means the last filled row, or there are also filled rows after this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, please. It will automatically hide the rows according to the changed value in "B14". Copy the code in the sheet module. In order to do that, select the sheet to be processed, right click on its page and choose "View Code". Copy the code there, go back in the sheet, start playing with values in "B14" and send some feedback about its behavior:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B14")) Is Nothing Then
    Dim lastRow As Long, visRows As Long
 
    If IsNumeric(Range("B14").Value) Then
       visRows = Range("B14").Value
    Else
       MsgBox "In range ""B14"" must be a number!": Exit Sub
    End If
     If visRows = 50 Then
       lastRow = 69
     Else
       lastRow = 70
     End If
     Range("A:A").EntireRow.Hidden = False 'make all rows visible
     Range(Range("A21").Offset(visRows), Range("A" & lastRow)).EntireRow.Hidden = True
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks FaneDuru. I've copied this code into VBA but no success. 
I have multiple worksheets if that makes a difference. The worksheet I'm trying to apply the macro to is named "Capacity Planner"
There is information past row 70 which is still required to be visible. Although I have added data validation to cell B14 so this figure cannot be above 50.
Sorry, my knowledge of macros is very basic so I may need to be stepped through.

Comment: @Ash Tonn:  What "no success" does mean? Do you receive an error? You don't, but the code does not hide anything, hide the wrong range, or what? So, do you want to hide the rows up to 69, in fact? If you run the code for the active cell, its name does not matter. If you need to run it without activation, you have to only change `Set sh = ActiveSheet` in `Set sh = Worksheets("SheetName")`. But which "B14" range to be used? Now, the code uses the one in the active sheet.

Comment: The code does not hide anything. I'm quite fresh to Macros so there is every chance I am missing a step along the way. Row 70 should be hidden always unless "n" = 50. So rows 71 onwards should be visible always.

Comment: @Ash Tonn:  It is not a matter of freshness, I think... When you run the code, are you sure that the sheet to be processed is activated?  If not, check that. When you say "I have multiple worksheets if that makes a difference", what do you mean? Do you want running the code for all those "multiple sheets" at once? How to behave the code in case of `n = 50`? To hide rows until 69? Adapted the code to behave in this way (to hide only until 69 in case of `n = 50`. Please, test it **on the active sheet**, which must contain number **in its "B14" range**... Does your active sheet has values in A:A?

Comment: Okay some further movements. The code works if I go View → Macros → View Macros → Run. However it doesn't update automatically when I change the number in B14. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: @Ash Tonn: But, how did you try the code before? Only looking at it?  What "update automatically" should mean? Did you say anything in your question about this aspect? Would you like the code to automatically do its job if you modify the B14 range value? If yes, it can be adapted. To make it run in Worksheet Change event. But, before that, I need you to clarify the issue and clearly explain what you need to code to do...

Comment: Yes I need the code to automatically do its job when B14 is modified.

Comment: @Ash Tonn:  I will adapt the code in some minutes. Do you know what a sheet event is? Can you see the sheet module in VBE?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken a sheet event is the module? So for this code the sheet event is testHideRowsB14

Comment: @Ash Tonn:  No! A sheet event is triggered by something changed in the sheet we are talking about. There are Sheet_Activate event, Sheet_Change event, Before_Delete and so on... For now, it is important to only know that they exists and act in the way I tried explaining. I adapted the code and explained where to copy it. Please, confirm that you understood and the code works as you need.

Comment: Right. Thanks for the explanation. I've copied the updated code. It works perfectly up to n = 49. However at n = 50 it only shows up to row 68 instead of row 70. Do you have a final fix for this?

Comment: I've managed to fix the error by updating both lastRow lines to lastRow = 71 and adding in a blank row at 71. The macro is working perfectly. Thank you very much for your patience and assistance.

Comment: @Ash Tonn:  It was a logic fracture in your request... 21 + 50 = 71. So, rows 70 is inside the range to be changed... I din not make this arithmetic. I thought you did it. But, glad I could help! In such cases, we here, when somebody spends some time and answer our question, tick the left side code check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**.  In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works... :)

Answer (score 0):

The following VBA code should work

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim rngWatched As Range, n As Long
  Set rngWatched = Me.Range("B14")
  If Not Intersect(Target, rngWatched) Is Nothing Then
    With Me.Range("A21:A70")
      .EntireRow.Hidden = True
      n = rngWatched.Value
      If n > 0 Then
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(n, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
      End If
    End With
  End If
End Sub
```

To use the code, please follow these steps:

- Press Alt+F11. This will take you to the VBA editor window
- On the left hand side you will see a project explorer
- Expand VBAProject(YOUR_EXCEL_FILENAME)
- Expand Microsoft Excel Objects
- Double-click on the relevant sheet. This will open the sheet class page
- Paste the code here
- Close the VBA editor window and go back to excel
- Make sure the file is then saved as Excel Macro-Enabled workbook (*.xlsm)